# How to get Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude to include in the head?

Tags: asp.net

The included script references, in particular jQuery, are being rendered after viewstate.  Is there a way to get this in the < head>?

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jQuery", "/scripts/jquery.js");
```

I am trying to register jquery.js in a user control's page load.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.  If it can't be done (with ClientScript), anyone have an idea why they didn't build it in?

**UPDATE**

The main feature of the ClientScript manager I need is the ability to only include a script once.  The control can appear many times on a page, but i only want one jQuery script include

Answer (score 24, accepted):

to directly inlcude it in the HEAD:

```
HtmlGenericControl Include = new HtmlGenericControl("script"); 
Include.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript"); 
Include.Attributes.Add("src", sInclude); 
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(Include);
```

you would want to check to make sure its not there already before adding it.

Comment: Another perfectly valid method, bypassing the PlaceHolder that I used.

Comment: Thank you Glennular, that check for uniqueness seems to be the useful bit of ClientScript

Comment: After struggling a lot. This is the perfect answer.

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem a while back, and I ended up not using RegisterClientScriptInclude.

I placed a placeholder in the header of the page, and added the script tag to the placeholder via a HtmlGenericControl.

I'll see if I can find my code and I'll edit my answer with it.

**EDIT**

I couldn't find my code, so I just re-created it:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</head>    
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

And the Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HeadPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(/* Your control here */);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Yea, everything I'm reading out there indicates it will not render into the head.

Comment: This was perfect - the placeholder is useful to locate the scripts exactly where you want in the head, mainly just for neatness. I also used a separate one for stylesheets. The Page.Header.Controls.Add approach only appends to the end, so everything tends to get intermingled. With PlaceHolder, the scripts are grouped; stylesheets are grouped.

Answer (score 3):

Hey, old question, but maybe this is still of interest for someone.

I am creating a own UserControl with .net 3.5sp1, ran into the same problems. Following solution works for me.

This code is from the `UserControl` class:

```
protected void Page_Init( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    const string scriptKey = "UserControlScript";

    if( !Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered( Page.GetType(), scriptKey ) )
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude( Page.GetType(), scriptKey, ResolveClientUrl("~/js/UserControl.js" ) );
    }
}
```

I used `Page_Init` because I need to do some more initialization that has to be done before `Page_Load` of the nesting page is called.

Answer (score 1):

It appears its not possible to use Page.ClientScript to add scripts to the header of the page.